# Must a driving instructor accompany a learner on a motorcycle in India?

Tags: india, driving, motor-vehicle, motorcycle

I am an Indian citizen who recently entered adulthood. I have thus been learning how to drive vehicles. To be able to drive a vehicle in order to gain experience, you need a Learner's license, as is the case in many countries. If you are learning to drive a car, you must be accompanied by a person who holds a valid driver's license, who can take control of the vehicle if the situation arises.
I read in some official document that a person learning to drive a vehicle must be accompanied by a person holding a valid learner's license, who is in a position to commandeer the vehicle if the situation arises. Now this makes sense for 4-wheelers, but what about 2-wheelers? Do they want an instructor to ride pillion? A pillion obviously is not in a position to commandeer the motorcycle, also it adds weight to the bike, making it more difficult to control.
Asking since I have been driving a motorcycle on a Learner's license with no pillion instructor, and a legal situation may arise where this is questioned in the court of Law.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a separate requirement for motorcycles? In Oregon (US), you have to have a licensed rider near you (I don't remember if they're supposed to be in front of, behind, or beside you), and IIRC you have to get a "motorcycle instruction permit" separate from the four-wheel vehicle permit, and to ride alone, you need a motorcycle endorsement on your regular license. The law in India might be similar.

Answer (score 6):

If we go by Indian case law (as we should), you have to find a way. The relevant case is [K.P. Adbul Gafoor v. New India Assurance Ltd](https://www.casemine.com/judgement/in/5e96dfe64653d05364586031), where appellant drove on a motor cycle on a learner's permit without a licensed driver positioned correctly, in violation of Rule 3 of the Rules, and smacked someone. The bulk of the case is about the insurance and liability consequences of violating the rule: the main point here is that the court deemed this to violate the rules.